# How do I access the FM chip in a Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to build a flutter app that utilizes the inbuilt FM radio chip. I don't want an online radio streaming service. I want a terrestrial one.

How do I go about achieving that?
Where should I be looking?
Which packages should I try or if it comes to writing native code, which documentation should I dive into?

I have a preinstalled radio app that plays local radio broadcasts (terrestrial radio) on my LG K9 LM-X210 that inspired the idea.

Comment: Very few phones actually have a FM chip, iPhone doesn't from 7+ and Google doesn't have a public API for accessing it. The only company I know that has created an API for accessing the chip is Sony. Odds are your app uses internet based streaming rather than from the radio.